# Acceptable variance within treatments tested with one way ANOVA

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, mathematical-statistics, multiple-comparisons

I have six treatment means I am testing (including one control), each with three replicates. I used a Levene's test to verify equal variance, and this did not yield a significant result. My treatment group #2 though has an outlier that makes the variance much higher in this group even if it is not 'significantly' different, and it appears to throw off the results of the anova. With all groups included, I get no significance (F~0.11). However, using t-tests I get significance (p~0.02) between 5 and 1 as well as 5 and 3. Should I proceed in reporting anova or t-test results? I realize using multiple t-tests increases type 1 error.